# Insert song times and pointers into mp3 full album

Tags: mp3, music

I have a full album in mp3, 50 minutes of music. I need some strategy to give it a way to easily navigate trought the album songs, being able to choose song. This would allow a more productive listening, also, I need to add song names if possible. Probably there is a "container" of mp3 files that can do that, or a conversion (with the condition of not splitting the album into many pieces) to a format in wich there are pointers to songs, and be able to play that with VLC.
If there no other choice, probably I should separate songs in mp3 and arrange them in a folder. But I want to know if the former said is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer directly to the question you've asked, but over the last decade or so I've found the easiest way (in terms of direct usage, tool support, application support, etc.) to manage this is to break each song out into it's own MP3. The MP3s can then be properly ID3 tagged with Name/Artist/Album and added to a playlist (*.m3u). I put the MP3s and the playlist into a folder, along with the album art (named "folder.jpg" or "folder.png"). Pretty much every audio player will understand the Playlist, which will allow you to easily load all the songs into VLC and jump between songs, see song names / artist info, etc.

You can then easily copy/move the entire folder around, etc.